# Perfect pairing on quotient by a polynomial $A[x]/\langle f\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

There's an interesting book by Fuhrmann called *A Polynomial Approach to Linear Algebra*. I'm trying to understand bits and pieces of it and generalize to commutative rings (as opposed to fields).

Throughout, $A$ is a commutative ring.

1. In (5.62) Fuhrmann defines a pairing on the ring $A(\!( \tfrac 1x )\!)$ as follows: $$\langle \sum_{i=-\infty}^{n_a}a_ix^i,\sum_{i=-\infty}^{n_b}b_ix^i\rangle = \sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_ib_{-i-1}.$$
2. In 5.34, Fuhrmann defines reciprocal $A$-linear isomorphisms $\tfrac 1x A[\![ \tfrac 1x ]\!]\rightleftarrows A[x]^\vee={}_A\mathsf{Mod}(A[x],A)$, with the rightward map given by $h\mapsto \langle h,-\rangle$ and the leftward map given by $\varphi\mapsto \tfrac 1x\sum_{i=0}^\infty \tfrac{\varphi(x^i)}{x^i}$.
3. In (5.64), he defines defines a pairing on $A[x]/\langle p\rangle$ by using an extension of the previous pairing to the localization at $p\in A[x]$ as follows $$\langle f,g\rangle_{/p}=\langle \tfrac fp,g\rangle=\langle f,\tfrac gp\rangle.$$ If I understand correctly, Fuhrmann claims this is a perfect pairing.

---

**Questions:**

1. Can the new pairing be defined without resorting to formal division by $p$?
2. How does the isomorphism of the second imply the new pairing $\langle -,=\rangle_{/p}$ is perfect?
3. What is the motivation for the first pairing at all? For instance, why not return $\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty a_i b_{-i}$?

Comment: I don't know anything about the first two questions, but as for the third question, the $-1$ is a "residue" pairing; you can write this pairing down on Laurent series over $\mathbb{C}$ by multiplying and then taking a contour integral around the unit circle, which isolates coefficient of the term $\frac{1}{z}$ in the product (the residue at $0$) and ignores the others.